# Change one letter in a string to make new word c++

Tags: c++, stl

Find set of words in a dictionary that differ by only one letter from any given four-letter input.
For example, the word "desk" can have the second letter replaced by 'i' and get "disk".

This is what I have so far. I am stuck on how to even start this process, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
int main (int argc, char ** argv) {
    string word;
    int count; // count total # of words after each query 
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(argv[1]);

    while (cin) {
        cout << "Please input a 4 letter word:"; 
        cin >> word;
        if (word.size() == 4) {
            transform(word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), _tolower);
            count++;
            
            cout << word << endl;
            cout << "Total " << count << " words." << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "wrong length!" << endl;
    }
    
    }

    
}
```

Sample output

> Please input a 4 letter word:win
>
> > wrong length!wine
> >
> > > aine bine cine dine eine fine gine hine kine line mine nine pine rine sine tine vine wane wene wicewide wife wile wime wina wind wing wini wink winn wino wins wint winy wipe wire wise wite wive wone wyne
> > > Total 41 words.

Comment: What do you think you will have to do?

Comment: write a function `distance(string,string)` then use a `std::vector<string>` as dictionary and find elements with distance = 1, please show your attempt.

Comment: There's no such thing as a big problem. Only little problems ganging up on you. Break the job down into little problems and keep breaking them down until you know how to solve all of them. Solve the little problems. Test them to make sure they're really solved. Assemble the little solutions into bigger solutions, testing as you go.

Comment: @JHBonarius So i think i need to have a counter and compare each word in the dictionary to the inputted word. then if the first letter matches, increment the counter by one and so on for the rest of the letters.

Comment: I would probably read the relevant dictionary words (eg just the 4 letter ones) into a set. Then I would loop through each letter in the word and try replacing the letter with each letter of the alphabet and looking up each new word (remembering to skip over the original word) to see if it is in the set. Eg for desk, try aesk, besk, cesk, eesk, fesk, through to zesk, then try dask, dbsk, dcsk etc

Answer (score 2):

A nice algorithm to use for this is [`std::inner_product`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inner_product). Assuming you have 2 strings `word` and `test`, both of equal length, you can sum up the number of characters that are pairwise different between them:

```
int res = std::inner_product(word.begin(), word.end(), 
                             test.begin(), 
                             0,
                             std::plus{}, 
                             std::not_equal_to{});
```

If this result is less than `2`, then the `test` and the `word` strings are different in at most one character:

```
if (res < 2)
{
  // ... successful match
}
```

You should probably wrap this in a function that takes 2 strings, and returns a `bool`, so you can call this function for all the words in the set that you want to test.

Comment: his professor will probably not think he found this out himself ;)

Comment: @JHBonarius Even better. It's not my intent to help students cheat on assignments (if that is indeed what the OP is trying to do). I just want to write answers that are useful to future visitors. In fact, if `<numeric>` was rangified in C++20, I would have shown that version instead :)